# query multiple columns and date

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has 4 `columns(date,gr1,gr2,gr3)` the `(gr)` columns have grades ranging from (a to f).

```
date        gr1 gr2 gr3
2012-1-1    a   b   c
2011-11-31  b   d   c
2011-11-30  c   a   f
2011-11-29  a   b   f
2011-11-28  f   b   c
2011-11-27  a   c   d
2011-11-26  c   a   b
```

I need to query the following:
I need to Select when any columns value has an 'a' followed by an 'f' grade on the following day, no matter which columns has the grade.

I'm a newbie and any help would be greatly appreciated... happy new year to all!

Comment: how u expect  the result? and what have u tried?

Comment: On what database will these be run?

Comment: using mysql ....all I want is to be to run the query and have it display the 4 columns.

Answer (score 1):

When making comparisons, one approach is to bring records being compared together into the same row.  Since you want to compare records from the "current to the following day", you can join the table on itself with a difference of one day in the date.  This is done with the `DATEDIFF` function which calculates the number of days different between two dates.

**Query 1**:

```
select
  today.*,
  followingday.date as ndate, followingday.gr1 as ngr1,
  followingday.gr2 as ngr2, followingday.gr3 as ngr3
from mytable today
join mytable followingday on DATEDIFF(followingday.date, today.date) = 1
```

This will give the following results, with successive day's values combined with the previous day (I have renamed the columns from `followingday` with a prefix of `n` so that all the columns have unique names, otherwise they won't all show in the result set):

**Results ([DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cee16/4))**:

```
|                            DATE | GR1 | GR2 | GR3 |                           NDATE | NGR1 | NGR2 | NGR3 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| November, 30 2011 00:00:00+0000 |   c |   a |   f | December, 01 2011 00:00:00+0000 |    b |    d |    c |
| November, 29 2011 00:00:00+0000 |   a |   b |   f | November, 30 2011 00:00:00+0000 |    c |    a |    f |
| November, 28 2011 00:00:00+0000 |   f |   b |   c | November, 29 2011 00:00:00+0000 |    a |    b |    f |
| November, 27 2011 00:00:00+0000 |   a |   c |   d | November, 28 2011 00:00:00+0000 |    f |    b |    c |
| November, 26 2011 00:00:00+0000 |   c |   a |   b | November, 27 2011 00:00:00+0000 |    a |    c |    d |
```

Now that the results are combined together into a single row, we can apply some logic to the data.  In this case, the rule is "any columns value has an 'a' followed by an 'f' grade on the following day, no matter which columns has the grade."  So any of the grades are an `a` on the current day, followed by any of the grades being an `f` on the following day:

**Query 2**:

```
...
where (today.gr1 = 'a' or today.gr2 = 'a' or today.gr3 = 'a')
  and (followingday.gr1 = 'f' or followingday.gr2 = 'f' or
         followingday.gr3 = 'f')
```

**Results ([DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cee16/5))**:

```
|                            DATE | GR1 | GR2 | GR3 |                           NDATE | NGR1 | NGR2 | NGR3 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| November, 29 2011 00:00:00+0000 |   a |   b |   f | November, 30 2011 00:00:00+0000 |    c |    a |    f |
| November, 27 2011 00:00:00+0000 |   a |   c |   d | November, 28 2011 00:00:00+0000 |    f |    b |    c |
```

The results show that there was a grade of `a` on `11-27-11`, followed by a grade of `f` on `11-28-11`.  Likewise, there was a grade of `a` on `11-29-11`, followed by a grade of `f` on `11-30-11`.  These should be the only results that satisfy the rule.

Comment: wow...thanks so much for your quick response......if only our politicians would be as effective...LOL

Comment: wow...thanks so much for your quick response......if only our politicians would be as effective...LOL  Query 2 is what I was looking for. In Query1 though, don't need to show the Dec 1 result, because there is no 'f' grade on that day.. But your assistance is so greatly appreciated!

Comment: @NJPLima: I was just taking it step-by-step to show my thought process.  The first query just links together the two days with no filtering.  The second query then builds on that by adding filtering based on the business logic rules.  This isn't the only approach either - you could use an `exists` clause to check for a matching row from the next day with `f` grade, for each row that has an `a` grade.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked fine...I'll be looking to learn a bit more about using EXISTS later..Thxs for the heads up.